# Malicious third-party dependency vulnerability possible in Tezos?

Tags: security

Lately there was a compromised npm package, which was used as a dependency in various projects. The code allowed the attacker to steal funds if certain conditions were met.

Could Tezos become a victim of a similar attack with for example a hijacked OCaml dependency such as a commonly used library? How do the active developers working on the code try to prevent this? Don't quote me on this, but in an older video I can remember @ArthurB talk about code coverage - which is great. Are there other security measures in place? Or is it the job of the bakers to set up a sufficient firewall to prevent outside communication?

Comment: Can you please name the "compromised npm package"? And a reference to a description of the possible attack you mention? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it's relevant to mention the "compromised npm package" specifically. It's a general threat from using 3rd party libraries and something that the core devs should have a strategy to defend against.

Comment: @Klassare : It's always good if one can give concrete examples. As for the question itself, the formulation  did not hint to a general threat --as the trigger--, but to a specific one ("The code allowed the attacker to steal funds": which code?). If XTZST2O wants to add some references, I'm sure this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's something to be careful about. If you look in `scripts/version.sh` you will see that the opam repository is pinned to a particular hash. This enforces Tezos being compiled against a specific version of the package repository.

This helps a great deal, and protects against the repository being hacked for instance. However, that repo hash may need to be updated over time, as new version of the dependencies are released. This introduces the need to monitoring upstream packages to ensure that they do not introduce backdoors.

This is a thorny problem that every software has to contend with, and there's no silver bullet. Minimizing dependencies, pinning their versions, and reviewing their changes when moving to a newer version is a good start.

Comment: Pinning dependencies to specific version hashes is kind of a silver bullet in my opinion, even though it requires some effort to edit `version.sh`.